# Can't invoke Activity 2 after Activity 1 is saved to database successfully using Restful web service

Tags: java, android, rest

I've been getting this issue for a long time.
It is a process of registering a user, I break it into 2 activities:

Activity 1 - RegisterActivity (email, password)

Activity 2 - RegisterCustomerActivity (Last Name, First Name, Birthday, ect..).

Activity 2 can only be invoked only when the Activity 1 is finished successfully. Unfortunately, after finishing Activity 1, user is saved to DB successfully, system gets lost, can't go back to the UI Thread, could you please help? Is there anything to do with Thread?

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    register_btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean isResgisterUserSuccess = registerUser();
            //02/18/2017: Error: After registering a user successfully, system gets lost, 
            //can't return to the UI thread, it doesn't go to the if loop below to invoke the startRegisterCustomerActivity()
            if (isResgisterUserSuccess == true){
                startRegisterCustomerActivity();
            }   
            //startRegisterCustomerActivity();
        }
    });
}       

private boolean registerUser(){
    String email = register_edtEmail.getText().toString();
    String pass = register_edtPassword.getText().toString();
    String mobile = register_edtMobile.getText().toString();
    resultString = "";
    isSuccess = false;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    if (Utility.isNotNull(email)&&Utility.isNotNull(pass)&&Utility.isNotNull(mobile)){
        if (Utility.isEmailValid(email)) {
            if (Utility.isPhoneNumberValid(mobile)){
                params.put("username", email);
                params.put("password", pass);
                params.put("phone", mobile);
                params.put("description", "User Description");
                params.put("category", "C");    
                invokeWS(params);
            } else {
                isSuccess = false;
                resultString = "Please enter valid phone number!";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            isSuccess = false;
            resultString = "Please enter valid email!";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    } else {
        isSuccess = false;
        resultString = "Please enter email, password and mobile!";
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return isSuccess;
}

private void invokeWS(RequestParams params){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response){
            JSONObject json;
            register_prgDialog.hide();
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(response);
                if(json.getBoolean("status")){
                    System.out.println("Inside invokeWS, inside try, status = " + json.getBoolean("status"));
                    isSuccess = true;
                    resultString = "You registered successfully!";
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    resultString = json.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                isSuccess = false;
                resultString = "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!";
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content){
            register_prgDialog.hide();
            if (statusCode == 404){
                isSuccess = false;
                resultString = "Requested resource not found";
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                isSuccess = false;
                resultString = "Something went wrong at server end!";
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                isSuccess = false;
                resultString = "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]";
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startRegisterCustomerActivity(){
    System.out.println("Inside startRegisterCustomerActivity");
    Intent addRegisterCustomer = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, RegisterCustomerActivity.class);
    String email = register_edtEmail.getText().toString();
    String mobile = register_edtMobile.getText().toString();
    //Create Bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //Add your data to Bundle
    bundle.putString("Email", email);
    bundle.putString("Mobile", mobile);
    //Add the Bundle to Intent
    addRegisterCustomer.putExtras(bundle);
    //Fire the activity
    startActivity(addRegisterCustomer);
}
}
```

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how a debugger works.  A debugger would reveal more information than SO I believe.

Comment: there are 2 solution for this, since invokeWS is asynchronous, it will not give the result immidiately, either you loop to check whether invokeWS method has finished or put the calling of startRegisterCustomerActivity inside the onsuccess method of invokeWS.  REASON IS BECAUSE ASYNC RUNS ON ANOTHER THREAD AND AFTER YOU CALL registerUser() EVEN IF invokeWS() IS NOT FINISHED IT WILL GO TO THE NEXT LINE OF CODE WHICH IS CHECKING FOR isResgisterUserSuccess VARIABLE

Comment: Thank you vims liu, let me try your way, I'll update you then.

Comment: I called the startRegisterCustomerActivity inside the onsuccess method of invokeWS. It works!!! Thank you. However, I prefer to check if the invokeWS has finished to call the startRegisterCustomerActivity. The code is more clear and 'unit-isolated' that way, could you please suggest how to check if the invokeWS has finished? And please tell me how to mark this answer green? ;-) Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use AsyncTask when communicating to a server.

From android docs:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Comment: I tried AsyncTask, doesn't work, the reason it doesn't work is like vims liu said above. I will try his recommendation to startRegisterCustomerActivity inside the onsuccess method of invokeWS method.